# Kafka-python get number of partitions for topic

Tags: python, python-2.7, metadata, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using: https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python as a kafka api in Python. I want to get the number of partitions for a specified topic. How do I do that?

Answer (score 14):

Might be a slightly simplistic solution, but:

```
from kafka import KafkaClient

client = KafkaClient('SERVER:PORT')
topic_partition_ids = client.get_partition_ids_for_topic(b'TOPIC')
len(topic_partition_ids)
```

tested on Python 3.4.3 / kafka-python 0.9.3

Comment: consider adding:
a = len(topic_partition_ids)
print(topic_partition_ids)
print(a)

Comment: this has been deprecated, try using "partitions_for_topic": https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.partitions_for_topic

Comment: As suggested by @Alan try to use : client.cluster.partitions_for_topic(topic)

Answer (score 3):

For those of you using Confluent-Python or the enterprise API. This can be done this way:

```
cluster_data: ClusterMetadata = producer.list_topics(topic=TOPIC)
topic_data: TopicMetadata = cluster_data.topics[TOPIC]
available_partitions: PartitionMetadata = topic_data.partitions
print("Count of partitions:", len(available_partitions))
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while trying to solve this exact same problem.  I know the question is old, but here is the solution I came up with (using [Kazoo](https://kazoo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to talk to zookeeper):

```
from kazoo.client import KazooClient

class KafkaInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, hosts):
        self.zk = KazooClient(hosts)
        self.zk.start()

    def topics(self):
        return self.zk.get_children('/brokers/topics')

    def partitions(self, topic):
        strs = self.zk.get_children('/brokers/topics/%s/partitions' % topic)
        return map(int, strs)

    def consumers(self):
        return self.zk.get_children('/consumers')

    def topics_for_consumer(self, consumer):
        return self.zk.get_children('/consumers/%s/offsets' % consumer)

    def offset(self, topic, consumer, partition):
        (n, _) = self.zk.get('/consumers/%s/offsets/%s/%d' % (consumer, topic, partition))
        return int(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.8.10/kafka-python 2.0.2 Solution:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

def get_partitions_number(server, topic):
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        topic,
        bootstrap_servers=server
    )
    partitions = consumer.partitions_for_topic(topic)
    return len(partitions)
```

[partitions_for_topic](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.partitions_for_topic)

Answer (score 0):

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition

bootstrap_servers = "your_server"
topic = "your_topic"

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    auto_offset_reset="earliest",
    bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
    api_version=(1, 10, 1),
)

consumer.assign([TopicPartition(topic, 0)])
number_of_partitions = len(consumer.partitions_for_topic(topic))
```