# Kafka-python Get replication factor for a topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, metadata, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

Using this [library](https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python), I was able to get the `partition count per topic` but not able to get the `replication factor`. Closest question I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612228/kafka-python-get-number-of-partitions-for-topic/68646782#68646782) for reference.
Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use confluent-kafka library,

1. Create [AdminClient](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#module-confluent_kafka.admin)
2. Then [ListTopics](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.list_topics)
3. It will return [ClusterMetaData](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.ClusterMetadata)
4. Then, use [topics' metadata](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.TopicMetadata) from ClusterMetaData
5. TopicMetadata has [Partitions' metadata](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.PartitionMetadata) which has [replica details](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.PartitionMetadata.replicas)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works!
It was also easy getting the `configurations` by using `name` and `value` attributes.